# Why are my grayscale images showing up in black and white?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am doing some tests in opencv, looking at blurring and the result in discrete cosine transform (increasing kernel size with each loop).  I want to display the image and the dct result in the same frame so I can compare.

When I display them in separate frames, they look good.  But when I use np.hpstack or np.concatenate to display the blurred image and the dct, the grayscale image becomes really thresholded.  I can see a bit of black with kernel size 1, but after that it pretty much goes white after that in my loop.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

for i in xrange(1,31,2):
    median_blur = cv2.medianBlur(img,i)
    string = 'median_blur : kernel size - '+str(i)
    imf = np.float32(median_blur)/255.0  # float conversion/scale
    dst = cv2.dct(imf)           # the dct
    img2 = np.uint8(dst)*255.0    # convert back
    cv2.putText(median_blur,string,(20,20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,1,(0,0,0))
    vis = np.hstack([median_blur,img2])

    cv2.imshow('Blur',median_blur)
    cv2.imshow('dct',img2)
    cv2.imshow('together', vis)
    cv2.waitKey(500)
```

[image]

I think it must have something to do with median_blur and img2 being of different dimensions but I am confused because they display ok by themselves. Sorry but my screenshot cut off a bit of the 'together' window.  I am using greyscale because the dct only works on one channel at a time as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

The dct result was remaining a float64 because it was multiplied by 255.0 not 255.

The issue was diagnosed by looking at the dimensions and data type of the numpy arrays:

```
print median_blur.shape, median_blur.dtype
print img2.shape, img2.dtype
print vis.shape, vis.dtype
```

Initially I had:

```
(512, 512) uint8
(512, 512) float64
(512, 1024) float64
```

Then after changing `img2 = np.uint8(dst)*255.0` to `img2 = np.uint8(dst)*255` I got:

```
(512, 512) uint8
(512, 512) uint8
(512, 1024) uint8
```

[image]

EDIT:

one last thing.  I did NOT want to use the divide by 255 and *255 altogether!!  eliminating them gave the dct i wanted.  now you can beautifully see the effect of the different blurring filters on the dct.

```
imf = np.float32(blur)  # float conversion (NO scale)
dst = cv2.dct(imf)           # the dct
img2 = np.uint8(dst)    # convert back to unsigned 8bit image
```

[image]